# Is there a residually finite non-elementary hyperbolic group whose profinite completion is boundedly generated?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups

Is there a residually finite hyperbolic group $G$ that is not virtually cyclic, such that there exists finitely many procyclic closed subgroups $C_1, \dots, C_n$ of the profinite completion $\hat{G}$ of $G$ satisfying the property that for every $g \in \hat{G}$ there exist $c_1 \in C_1, \dots, c_n \in C_n$ with $g = c_1 \cdots c_n$ ?

It is known that $G$ itself can't be [boundedly generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundedly_generated_group).

Comment: Every non-elementary hyperbolic group contains a quasiconvex non-abelian free subgroup. If every hyperbolic group were residually finite then this subgroup, and all its finite-index subgroups, would be separable (by a theorem of Agol--Groves--Manning). I think it follows that the profinite completion would not be boundedly generated.  So I'm fairly certain no such example is known to exist.

Comment: @HJRW I am afraid that I am not convinced. There are boundedly generated (discrete and profinite) groups which contain free subgroups.

Comment: I guess you're right...  I'm not used to thinking about bounded generation.  Can you remind me of the proof that non-elementary hyperbolic groups aren't boundedly generated?

Comment: @HJRW The proof uses boundary dynamics, and a sketch appears in the link (in the question).

Comment: Thank you!  This is a very nice question.  I assume it's known that the profinite completion of a free group isn't boundedly generated?

Comment: @HJRW The fact that the profinite completion of a free group isn't boundedly generated is also explained in that link: Just note that $S_n$ is the image of your free group and use Landau's bound on the order of a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: In that case, I guess (although perhaps my intuition about bounded generation is incorrect again) that the profinite completion of a non-elementary, hyperbolic, virtually special group $G$ is never boundedly generated, since $\widehat{G}$ virtually retracts to a non-abelian profinite free group.

Comment: @HJRW It seems that you are right. If a group $G$ surjects onto a nonabelian free group, then its profinite completion is not boundedly generated.

Comment: The next natural question is whether the congruence completion of a lattice in $Sp(n,1)$ is boundedly generated.  As you know, it's open whether or not this is the full profinite completion.

Comment: @HJRW I think that the pro-congruence completion is always boundedly generated. There is a theorem saying that an arithmetic group has the congruence subgroup property if and only if the profinite completion is boundedly generated.

Comment: Ah-ha! Another relevant fact (also following from Agol--Groves--Manning) is that if every hyperbolic group is residually finite then every non-elementary hyperbolic group *virtually* surjects every finite group.  I suspect that's enough to deduce that the profinite completion is not boundedly generated.

Comment: @HJRW does that mean that there exists a finite index subgroup that surjects onto every finite group?

Comment: It means that, for every finite group, there exists a finite-index subgroup that surjects it. It's enough to contradict the congruence subgroup property. Is it enough to contradict bounded generation?

Comment: @HJRW I am afraid that this is may not be quite enough, because if there exists a closed free profinite subgroup in the profinite completion, then this property follows.

Comment: Apologies, you mentioned this above. What's an example of a boundedly generated profinite group containing a free profinite subgroup?

Comment: @HJRW I am ashamed to say that I can't come up with an example, but I feel that infinite index subgroups of boundedly generated (profinite) groups may be arbitrary.

Comment: It seems important to know the answer to this question!  I'll take the liberty of writing an answer with the conclusions of this conversation.

Comment: @HJRW good! I will think about it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm fairly certain that no example is known. Of course, it's a famous open problem whether every hyperbolic group is residually finite.  This turns out to be equivalent to many other questions about the profinite topology on hyperbolic groups (see, for instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0709 and http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~kapovich/PAPERS/dani.dvi.gz ).  It's very tempting to conjecture that the existence of a non-elementary hyperbolic group with boundedly generated profinite completion would imply the existence of a non-residually finite hyperbolic group.

Most of the hyperbolic groups that we know to be residually finite are known to be so because they are *cubulable* (i.e. the fundamental group of a compact, non-positively curved cube complex). [Agol's theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2810), which resolved the virtual Haken conjecture, implies that these groups are residually finite.  In this case, we can say more.   Any non-elementary, cubulable, hyperbolic group always has a finite-index subgroup that retracts to a non-abelian free group. It follows that the profinite completion virtually surjects a non-abelian profinite free group, and hence can't be boundedly generated.

In the other direction, one would like candidate positive examples; here, the first example to look at is a cocompact lattice $\Gamma$ in $Sp(n,1)$. The *congruence subgroup problem* is open for such lattices. This asks whether the profinite completion of $\Gamma$ is equal to the *congruence completion*, meaning the inverse limit of all the congruence quotients of $\Gamma$. If so, then $\Gamma$ is said to satisfy the *congruence subgroup property (CSP)*.

The lattice $\Gamma$ is linear, and hence certainly residually finite.  Nevertheless, Lubotzky observed that, if the CSP holds for $\Gamma$, then there is a non-residually finite hyperbolic group.  And, indeed, the OP points out in comments that the congruence completion of $\Gamma$ is known to be boundedly generated.

In summary, we can say that bounded generated of the profinite completion is closely tied to the existence of a non-residually finite hyperbolic group. On the one hand, in cubulable groups, which are very "robustly" residually finite, the profinite completion is not boundedly generated. And in quaternionic lattices, the most plausible source of a non-residually finite hyperbolic group would also lead to a non-elementary, residually finite hyperbolic group with boundedly generated profinite completion.